# apc.stat causes 500 internal server error

Tags: apache-2.2, php, alternative-php-cache

When I turn off `apc.stat` it causes a 500 internal server error. I checked the apache `error_log` and it's something about:

```
[Tue Jun 26 10:02:59 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  require(): Filename cannot be empty in /var/www/site1/public/index.php on line 17
[Tue Jun 26 10:02:59 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/site1/public/index.php on line 17
```

I checked that line and here's what it contains:

```
require('./wp-blog-header.php');
```

I don't see anything wrong with it. Here's my current APC config:

[image]

APC version: 3.1.10
PHP Version: 5.4.4

How do I resolve this error when i disable `apc.stat`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I regret I'm gonna have to answer my own question after a few times of google search and bites  of doughnut.

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61854

It's a bug when using relative includes and `apc.stat=0`